# Show descriptive message on screen for specific time on view click android

Tags: android, view

I want to add a  pop up like chat bubble(using onClickListener) on screen for a few seconds to describe a view and it's purpose. I don't want to use toast since it'll be unclear for my purpose. Is there anything I can use?

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

To have a toast message , try this code

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Replace hello world with the message u need

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to use Toast.